# NMEA simulate no signal

Tags: gps, nmea

To test a navigation software, I need to simulate a NMEA-GPS log where the device has no signal. I tried it by sending a line without any position information like this:

```
$GPRMC,144742,V,,,,,,,,,,A*5C
$GPRMC,144743,V,,,,,,,,,,A*5D
$GPRMC,144744,V,,,,,,,,,,A*5A
```

But I don't know if this is the common way a gps receiver handles it.

How can I send a line to the software, the same way real hardware would do, to tell the software there is no signal from satellites?

Comment: One useful comment: real device (Trimble) does not send `GPRMC` messages at all until it is ready. It sends only partially populated `GPCGA`, `GPGSA` and `GPGSV` ones.